# jquery binding a key value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am using spring mvc in my application. The service returns a json response like,

```
[{"Key1": "value1"}]
```

I need to bind only the value part from the response to a drop down list in a jquery dialog. I use an AJAX call to get the list of items and to bind it. But it binds the whole row in the drop down list, not the value.

The code I use for binding the response is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "countries/getname",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(msg) {
            alert("MSG:"+msg);//this gives {"Key1": "value1"}
            $.each(msg,function(key, val) {
                alert("KEY::"+key); //key is returned as 0
                alert("VALUE::"+val); //value is returned as{"Key1": "value1"}
                $('<option />', {value: key, text: val}).appendTo("#sampleResp");
            });
        },
        error : function() {
            $("#sampleResp").get(0).options.length = 0;
            $("#sampleResp").get(0).options[0] = new Option("None", "None");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The value field is the item and it has the following form:
`{ "Key1": "value1"}`
SampleResp is the ID of the dropdownlist.

The jsp code looks like this:

```
<div>
    <form:select path="sampleResp" cssClass="w200">                     
    </form:select>
</div>
```

How to extract only the value part from the response and bind it into the drop down using ajax call in jquery?

Comment: Looks like boken, please give complete code.

Comment: I will give you the solution in few fractions. just tell the HTML code. I think, code for jQuery is not present here :(

Comment: okay so finally here i am with solution. check the answer.. i have included fiddle also as example. i am sure you will be happy this time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an array of objects in the message.

Why don't you just send a map instead that is the values are just within `{ key1:"value1", key2:"value2"}`.

With this you can just access the values like this

```
$.each( msg, function(k, v)
{
   alert( "Key: " + k + ", Value: " + v );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this code, becouse you didn't provide enough info (what is #sampleResp?, what is Option?, what is msg?)

My guess is:

```
new Option(item[0]);
```

if it doesn't work provide info for console.log(msg)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has the `eval()` function that transforms the JSON text string into an object of the DOM, where you can access all the variables and their values​​.

On the other hand, if you're receiving that JSON string by calling via Ajax, just adding `dataType:"json"` option in the `$.ajax()` function will create automatically an object in the handler function.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'someUrl',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: handleData
});

function handleData(jsonObj) {
    var key1=jsonObj.key1;
    //key 1 now is "value1"
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

In fact, you can also use the function `$.getJSON()` as a simple way for do the same

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

Working code here :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'url_of_json_file',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: createDropDown
    });
    $.each(data[0], function(key, val) {
        items.push('<option id="' + key + '">' + val + '</option>');
    });
    $("#dropDown").append(items.join('')); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
All JSON values in drop down.
    <select id="dropDown">
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Assuming JSON content in file is of the below form:

```
[{ 
"Key1": "value1",
"key2":"value2"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well so here is the solution,

```
success : function(msg) {
      $.each(msg, function(index, elem) {
         $.each(elem, function(key, value){
            $('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>').appendTo($("#sampleResp"));
         });
    });
 }
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Bzf7j/

Comment: This binds the whole key value pair {"key1":"value1"} in the drop down. but i need to add only the value 1 part in my drop down

Comment: okay so finally here i am with solution. check the answer.. i have included fiddle also as example. i am sure you will be happy this time. :)

Answer (score 0):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S7XSh/1/)**

If you are getting this result in your alert:

```
alert(msg);
// {"Key1": "value1"}
```

It means that your response from server is **string**, so you must need to parse it as JSON:

```
msg = JSON.parse(msg);
alert(msg);
// [object Object]
```

Now, the other part of your code is correct:

```
$.each(msg,function(key, val) {
    $('<option />', {value: key, text: val}).appendTo("#sampleResp");
});
```

So your code looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "countries/getname",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(msg) {
            msg = JSON.parse(msg);
            $.each(msg,function(key, val) {
                $('<option />', {value: key, text: val}).appendTo("#sampleResp");
            });
        }
    });
});
```